# How to write this query

Tags: sql, performance, oracle, oracle11g, query-optimization

I am stuck in a query and need your help and suggestion.The situation is :

I have a table with structure as

JOB_ID ,  ITEM_ID ,  NEW_ITEM_ID , STATUS

Where job_id is a primary key and status can be AC,SB.

Now i want to write a query that selects only those rows from table which have STATUS as AC and for which none of ITEM_ID OR NEW_ITEM_ID is in the row for which status is SB.I have already written a query but it takes a lot of time so please help me writing the optimized query.This what i have written

```
SELECT * FROM (
      SELECT JOB_ID,NEW_ITEM_ID,ITEM_ID,STATUS 
      FROM X1 
      WHERE  STATUS='AC' 
      AND NEW_ITEM_ID IS NOT NULL
      MINUS
      ( SELECT T1.JOB_ID,T1.NEW_ITEM_ID ,T1.ITEM_ID ,T1.STATUS 
        FROM ( SELECT * 
               FROM X1
               WHERE STATUS IN 'AC' 
               AND NEW_ITEM_ID IS NOT NULL  ) T1 
      , ( SELECT * 
          FROM X1 
          WHERE STATUS IN ('PR','SB') 
          AND NEW_ITEM_ID IS NOT NULL  ) T2
    WHERE ( T2.ITEM_ID IN (T1.ITEM_ID,T1.NEW_ITEM_ID) 
                  OR T2.NEW_ITEM_ID IN  (T1.ITEM_ID,T1.NEW_ITEM_ID) 
       )
    AND T1.STATUS!=T2.STATUS 
   )
 ) T
```

**EDIT**

***This table is going to contain millions of records say around 30M.***

Comment: You have forgotten to specify `firebird` and `db2` in tags

Comment: Heh. @Algorithmist: Which DBMS are you _actually_ using?

Comment: @Algorithmist: Then, pray tell, why the MySQL and PostgreSQL tags?

Comment: @Tomalak i just want the logic.this is why.do you have any suggestion.

Comment: I suggest closing the question as _too localised_.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way would be to have a query that selects all ITEM_IDs and NEW_ITEM_IDs which status is SB, then have another query like this:

`SELECT * FROM table WHERE STATUS = 'AC' AND WHERE ITEM_ID NOT IN (the results of the previous query) AND WHERE NEW_ITEM_ID NOT IN (the results of the query for NEW_ITEM_IDs mentioned above)`.

Just an idea though but with the proper syntax I think that should work.

Comment: I did that also but it is also taking too much time.

Answer (score 0):

try this :

```
 select * from status where STATUS ='AC' or (STATUS ='SB' and ITEM_ID  is null) or  or (STATUS ='SB' and NEW_ITEM_ID is null)
```

Comment: You should start writing _words_ in your answers; code examples complement explanations!

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you are looking for (1) the rows where status is AC and (2) there is no other row where the item_id or new_item_id's match and the status is SB?

How about:

```
SELECT job_id, item_id, new_item_id, status
  FROM x1 a
 WHERE a.status = 'AC'
   AND NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM x1 b
                    WHERE b.status = 'SB'
                      AND ( b.new_item_id = a.item_id
                            OR b.item_id = a.new_item_id )
```

Answer (score 0):

> "This table is going to contain millions of records say around 30M"

This is one crucial piece of information but a couple of other key stats are missing.  How many rows match the status of 'PR','SB' and 'AC' ?  How many rows have `new_item_id` populated?   Are those columns indexed?

You 'select * from x1' in your sub-queries.  SELECT * is bad practice, a bug-waiting to happen.  However it is disastrous here, because you don't use any of the columns, but you're forcing the database to read the entire row for each entry in the result-sets.  The longer the rows the more expensive that is.  In the sub-query you really should be driving off just indexes if you can possibly do so.

Ideally, you would have a index on X1 ( STATUS, NEW_ITEM_ID, ITEM_ID, JOB_ID ).  Then you wouldn't hit the table at all.  But at the very least you need an index on (STATUS, NEW_ITEM_ID).  An index just on STATUS won't do you any good unless STATUS is highly selective - several hundred different values, evenly distributed.  (Which seems unlikely: in my experience most status columns have a handful of different states_.

Your posted query hits table X1 three times; that will take ages.   So the main thing is to reduce the number of times you hit the table.  This is where sub-query factoring can help:

```
with data as (  select job_id, new_item_id, item_id, status 
                from x1 
                where  status in ('PR','SB', 'AC' ) 
                and new_item_id is not null )
select t1.* 
from data t1
     , data t2
where t1.status = 'AC'
and t2.status in ( 'PR','SB' )
abd (t2.new_item_id in ( t1.new_item_id, t1.item_id )
     or t2.item_id in ( t1.new_item_id, t1.item_id ) )
/
```

So this query hits the table only once, and with a favourable index not even once.

If the query still takes too much time - or you can't wangle a helpful index - the other option for improving execution times against massive tables is parallel query.  This option is open to you if you have an Enterprise Edition license and a server with sufficient CPUs (and both those conditions should be true if you want to run an application database with multi-million row tables_.

```
with data as (  select /*+ parallel (x1, 4) */
                        job_id, new_item_id, item_id, status 
                 from x1 
                 ...
```